# Change the displayname of the sender when sending mail via o365?

Tags: email, office365

Is it possible to control the display name of the sender when sending mails with the office 365 `OutlookServicesClient`? 
I.e., I want to use, say `mailer@domain.com` as the sender which is configured with the name `some name@domain.com` in office 365. But for a given mail I want the from name to instead be `some other name@domain.com`.

I've tried this:

```
Message draftMessage = new Message
{
Subject = subject,
    Body = body,
    ToRecipients = toRecip,
    CcRecipients = ccRecip,
    From = new Recipient()
    {
        EmailAddress = new EmailAddress() { Address = "mailer@domain.com", Name = "Some other name@domain.com" }
    }
};
```

But the mail is still sent with the preconfigured name of `some name@domain.com`.

So, is what I want possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [reference documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesMessage) for the Message object, what you want to do is possible. However, logic tells me that shouldn't be possible, and furthermore, the testing I did showed me it wasn't possible (or isn't working). I will follow up on this and update this answer when I get a definitive answer, but at this time, it appears like you can't change the name of the sender (or it's broken).

**UPDATE:** The `From` property is writable. I've tested this using pure REST, so I can't speak exactly to what the client library you are using is doing, but I think the request is being transformed to prevent spoofing.

*It is possible to control the display name of the sender*, but you can only do so with other users in your Office 365 tenant. To do this, sign in to the Office 365 Admin Portal, go to **Users**, then **Active Users**, then select the user (User A) that you want to send on behalf of. Click **Edit** and select **Mailbox Permissions**. Add the alias or email address of the user (User B) who is running the code (the user authenticated with your app) to the first box under **Send email from this mailbox**. This will allow you to set the `From` property of a message sent by User B as User A.

I understand this isn't exactly what you were after, but having the ability to send email as *any* email address can lead to some bad stuff. Hope this helped!

Comment: Yup, kind of what I suspected. Additionally, from the link you posted, if you look at the spec for Recipient https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#Recipient (which is the type of the sender), there's not even a field for Name. Even though there clearly is a field there :)

Comment: Another good catch. I have someone looking into your first question. The second one I can handle myself. Thank you! Please continue to use this tag as we have a few people looking to help devs like you out! Have a good one!

Comment: @aeliusd, I updated my answer with more information. Hope this answers your question! :)